# Set delegate for IronSource mobile ads

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, ironsource

I am following this [tutorial](http://developers.ironsrc.com/ironsource-mobile/ios/ios-sdk/#step-2) however I cannot figure out how to set the delegate. I have everything else set up and the ad is displaying but I can not run any code when the ad is closed because I am not sure how to set up the delegate. I tried to use my ad placement name but that wasn't it so I am not sure how I would set up the delegate in this case.

```
class DetailViewController: ISRewardedVideoDelegate {

@IBAction func ironSourceActionAd(_ sender: Any) {

    IronSource.showRewardedVideo(with:UIViewController(), placement: "DefaultRewardedVideo")
}

public func rewardedVideoHasChangedAvailability(_ available: Bool) {
}

public func rewardedVideoDidEnd() {
}

public func rewardedVideoDidStart() {
}

public func rewardedVideoDidClose() {
    text()
    print("closed")
}

public func rewardedVideoDidOpen() {
   print("Opened")
}

public func rewardedVideoDidFailToShowWithError(_ error: Error!) {
}

public func didReceiveReward(forPlacement placementInfo: ISPlacementInfo!) {
}
public func didClickRewardedVideo(_ placementInfo: ISPlacementInfo!) {
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    IronSource.initWithAppKey("72c23e35")
  error here//  IronSource.setRewardedVideoDelegate(DetailViewController)
    ISIntegrationHelper.validateIntegration()

}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

[The tutorial's `Step 2`](https://developers.ironsrc.com/ironsource-mobile/ios/ios-sdk/#step-1) teaches how to set up delegate. It seems like you need to complete `Step 2` first, before `Step 3`, and `Step 4`.

[image: Tutorial, step 2]

Comment: Yes the problem is I don't know how to set up the delegate correctly

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you haven't set the UserID. From the Ironsource help docs:

> Make sure you’ve set the userID before you initialize the ironSource SDK in order to successfully reward your users.

Here is how I did it in my viewDidLoad function:

```
    // Ironsource set up
    IronSource.setRewardedVideoDelegate(self)

    let userID = IronSource.advertiserId() // Ironsource generates a userID automatically for each user
    IronSource.setUserId(userID)

    let appKey = "xxxxxxx" // from my Ironsource dashboard
    IronSource.initWithAppKey(appKey, adUnits: [IS_REWARDED_VIDEO])
```

Comment: If I have my own userId for my app should I just ignore calling `advertiserId()` function

Comment: @Learn2Code I'm afraid I can't because I do not use rewarded video anymore and have deleted this code.

Comment: I keep getting this error `Error Domain=Supersonic.com Code=508 "Rewarded Video Show Fail - Show Rewarded Video cannot be called before Init is complete" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Rewarded Video Show Fail - Show Rewarded Video cannot be called before Init is complete}` do you know what I need to do to resolve?

Comment: @Learn2Code I do not know, but you have an error code and a fairly explicit error message so contact Ironsource support and ask them.